# How to crop an image with an eliwith CSS

Tags: html, css

I used the following code to crop a banner. What this code does is making it look like the banner is flowing into the white background - its bottom border is an eliptical shape.

What I want to do is invert this so that it looks like the white background is flowing into the banner, or in other words, the bottom border is an eliptical shape that points inwards.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
  .box {
    height: 33vh;
    background-image: 
url(image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 
center;
    background-repeat: no- 
repeat;
    position: relative;
    clip-path: ellipse(100% 
100% at 50% 0%);
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Help